# Is it possible to creating a Service without starting it?

Tags: android

I wonder, is it possible to create a `Service`, set some data, and then start it? I haven't come across a thread specific to this problem, so I would like to know if it is possible (if it is known of course).

My problem is that I have a `Service` which listens to a `DatagramSocket`, but the socket in question needs to be set after creation, but before the start of the `Service`. The setting of the socket happens through the use of a `Broadcast` (I broadcast 2 `Strings` which hold the IP-Address & Port and the `BroadcastReceiver` then constructs a socket for me).

When the `Service` is started, a `Thread` will start to run and listen to the supposedly created socket. This, sadly, doesn't happen. The socket will remain `null` and I can't set it when the `Thread` is running (This is another issue I hope to tackle in the future, if anybody got any ideas about this, please notify me).

So, is what I want possible, or should I come up with another construct for achieving this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it in another way now, I create the `DatagramSocket` in the `onCreate` method in the `Service class`. I still use the `BroadcastReceiver` to update the `socket` though.

On a further note: the `Service` creates a `Thread`, which uses the `socket`, so I had to suspend the `Thread` before editing the `socket`. I've paused the `Thread` using a `volatile boolean` (which forces all `Objects` who use it, to use the most recently updated version or something, I'm not an expert). The `Thread` calls the `wait()` method to suspend. Snapping it out of the `wait()` requires a set on the `boolean` value and a call to `notify()`. Stopping the thread is done by modifying another `volatile` variable and then calling the `interrupt()` method on the `Thread` to snap it out of any `sleep()` routines. Eventually this causes the `Thread` to finish it's `run()` method.

Sorry to put you on a sidetrack on how I stop or suspend/resume a `Thread`, but it is actually useful to know if you don't know how to do it... It took me a while to find, so I thought I'd share it with you...

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder, is it possible to create a Service, set some data, and then start it?

No.

> My problem is that I have a Service which listens to a DatagramSocket, but the socket in question needs to be set after creation, but before the start of the Service.

Sorry, what you want is not possible.

> The setting of the socket happens through the use of a Broadcast (I broadcast 2 Strings which hold the IP-Address & Port and the BroadcastReceiver then constructs a socket for me).

Why not eliminate every `BroadcastReceiver` and use `startService()` to pass the IP address and port to the `Service` via `Intent` extras?

Comment: Because I would like the socket to be editable. When I set a different port in my configuration activity, I want the socket to be updated with the new port, hence the broadcast...

Comment: @ThaMe90: Use `SharedPreferences` and `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

Comment: I know `SharedPreferences` can be used for more than storing data when an application is closed, but I don't see how I should use them here... Could you show a bit of code to explain yourself?

Comment: @ThaMe90: I don't have an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` sample handy. Try a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very much guessing here but when you define your Service in the `AndroidMainfest.xml` you can set the `android:enabled` attribute of it. Is it possible to programmatically disable the service -> create an instance of it -> initialize it as you see fit -> then enable and start it?

Comment: Now here I see a flaw though.. You can't create an instance of a Service, or of an Activity for that matter. :/